# Método de encriptado en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encriptación

tengo un desafío como principiante en programación y es encriptar y desencriptar a través de Js con parte de código HTML y no se en que le estoy errando.

alguien me podría iluminar?

muchas gracias desde ya

[image: script]

[image: HTML]

****index.html****

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="titulo">código secreto</h1>

  <main class="main">
    <section class="form box">
      <form action="">
        <label for="input-texto">Solo letras minúsculas, sin acento</label>
        <input class="text-input" type="text" name="input-texto" id="input-texto" placeholder="Ingrese el texto aqui">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="encriptar!" id="btn-encriptar">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="desencriptar!" id="btn-desencriptar">
      </form>
    </section>
  
    <section class="msg box">
      <h2 id="">Mensaje encriptada:</h2>
      <input class="text-input-salida" type="text" id="msg">
      <input class="btn" type="submit" value="copiar" id="btn-copy">
    </section>
  </main>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="Copiar-pegar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function encriptar (){
        var texto = document.querySelector("#input-texto").value;
        var textoCifrado = texto.replace(/e/gi, "enter").replace(/i/gi, "imes").replace(/a/gi, "ai").replace(/o/gi, "ober").replace(/u/gi, "ufat");
        document.querySelector(".text-input-salida").value = textoCifrado;
        document.querySelector("#input-texto").value;

}

var boton1 = document.querySelector("#btn-encriptar");
boton1.onclick = encriptar;

function desencriptar (){
        var texto = document.querySelector("#input-texto").value;
        var textoCifrado = texto.replace(/enter/gi, "e").replace(/imes/gi, "i").replace(/ai/gi, "a").replace(/ober/gi, "o").replace(/ufat/gi, "u");
        document.querySelector(".text-input-salida").value = textoCifrado;
        document.querySelector("#input-texto").value;

}

var boton2 = document.querySelector("#btn-desencriptar");
boton2.onclick = desencriptar;
```

Comment: buenas, en si que deseas realizar

Comment: la idea es que el usuario ponga un mensaje, y clickeando el boton encriptar reempaza las vocales por otras palabras.                                                           "e" es convertido para "enter" 
"i" es convertido para "imes"
"a" es convertido para "ai"
"o" es convertido para "ober"
"u" es convertido para "ufat"

Comment: Por favor, coloca tu código escrito para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Edite la publicación para que puedan ver el código, perdón

Comment: Te bota algún error? en la parte de la lógica veo al menos un fallo, cuando reemplazas las `a` por `ai` estás convirtiendo ese `ai` en `aimes` porque también se está aplicando el reemplazo de las `i`

Comment: si eso, lo supuse, pero ni siquiera encripta el mensaje y la consola no me bota ningún error

Comment: Cuales es tu error, he probado tu codigo aca https://jsfiddle.net/gsa2ycb4/ y solo cambie los submit por button para que se ejecute y "funciona" bien, dinos exactamente que es lo que necesitas

Comment: cuando abro el código en mi navegador, tipeo un texto, le doy al botón encriptar y no aparece el texto encriptado en la segunda box donde tendría que aparecer el resultado encriptado, es como si la página se actualizara.

Comment: Verificaste el codigo que te deje?  https://jsfiddle.net/gsa2ycb4

Comment: en el compilador web, el programa "funciona" pero en el navegador no, que raro,

Comment: Pero copiaste y pegaste igual al que te deje? yo realize los cambios que te comente arriba

Comment: gracias, josue, ahora si funciona!, ahora tengo que ver la logica que comentaba "aguardientico" mas arriba

Comment: Perfecto, tu error era referente al Submit

Comment: @Josue Vargas Por favor evitemos fomentar la mala práctica de copiar/pegar. Si tienes observaciones que hacer es mejor que las hagas en una respuesta. @Lautaro rodriguez, para el problema que mencionas, lo mejor sería convertir carácter por carácter y no todo en conjunto ya que al usar `replace()` y anidar las salidas, provocas el comportamiento incorrecto, p.e. `aieou` se vuelve `aeou`.

Comment: @JosueVargas Muchisimas gracias, se puede dejar un favorito, medalla algo acá? por la ayuda?

Comment: @Lautarorodriguez ya te dejo una respuesta

Comment: @ricardo-dlc no pense en una respuesta por lo sencillo, pero ya la coloco, gracias bro

Comment: @ricardo-dlc entiendo tu punto Ricardo, muchas gracias por ayudarme a mejorar. El problema es que soy muy nuevo, y no sé como hacerlo :(, pero voy a seguir investigando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error es porque tienes *Submit*
en vez de *Button* y el formulario se envia y no deja que el JS pueda funcionar.

Tu código funcional solo cambiando los **submit**

```js
function encriptar (){
    var texto = document.querySelector("#input-texto").value;
    var textoCifrado = texto.replace(/e/gi, "enter").replace(/i/gi, "imes").replace(/a/gi, "ai").replace(/o/gi, "ober").replace(/u/gi, "ufat");
    document.querySelector(".text-input-salida").value = textoCifrado;
    document.querySelector("#input-texto").value;
    }


    
var boton1 = document.querySelector("#btn-encriptar"); boton1.onclick = encriptar;

function desencriptar (){ var texto = document.querySelector("#input-texto").value; var textoCifrado = texto.replace(/enter/gi, "e").replace(/imes/gi, "i").replace(/ai/gi, "a").replace(/ober/gi, "o").replace(/ufat/gi, "u"); document.querySelector(".text-input-salida").value = textoCifrado; document.querySelector("#input-texto").value;

}

var boton2 = document.querySelector("#btn-desencriptar"); boton2.onclick = desencriptar;
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="titulo">código secreto</h1>

  <main class="main">
    <section class="form box">
      <form action="">
        <label for="input-texto">Solo letras minúsculas, sin acento</label>
        <input class="text-input" type="text" name="input-texto" id="input-texto" placeholder="Ingrese el texto aqui">
        <input class="btn" type="button" value="encriptar!" id="btn-encriptar">
        <input class="btn" type="button" value="desencriptar!" id="btn-desencriptar">
      </form>
    </section>
  
    <section class="msg box">
      <h2 id="">Mensaje encriptada:</h2>
      <input class="text-input-salida" type="text" id="msg">
      <input class="btn" type="button" value="copiar" id="btn-copy">
    </section>
  </main>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="Copiar-pegar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ya solo te queda mejorar tu lógica de encriptado para darle más seguridad.